# Can't understand why similiar test make 1 pass and not the other, can't spot it

Tags: javascript, testing, enzyme

This is a simple test of simulating comment existing in textarea, while first test is passing, next one simulating submiting text from textarea, running handleSubmit (connected to my form for now) which clear the textarea, but test pointing that comment is expected (poiting to  => .toEqual("");

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper.find("textarea").simulate("change", {
      target: { value: "new comment" }
    });


    wrapper.update();
  });

  it("has a text area that user can type into", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find("textarea").prop("value")).toEqual("new comment");
  });

  it("simulate button click (in real form submit) and clear textarea", () => {
    wrapper.update();
    wrapper.find("form").simulate("submit");
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.find("textarea").prop("value")).toEqual("");
  });
});

edit: here's the component I wanted to test...

    import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../actions";

class CommentBox extends Component {
  state = {
    comment: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ comment: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.saveComment(this.state.comment);
    this.setState({ comment: "" });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubumit}> <-------------- TYPO :(
        <h2>Add a comment:</h2>
        <textarea onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.comment} />
        <div>
          <button>Submit comment</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  actions
)(CommentBox);
```

Comment: Without seeing the actual code it is quite hard to get what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper.find("textarea").simulate("change", {
      target: { value: "new comment" }
    });


    wrapper.update();
  });

  it("has a text area that user can type into", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find("textarea").prop("value")).toEqual("new comment");
  });

  it("simulate button click (in real form submit) and clear textarea", () => {
    wrapper.find("form").simulate("submit");
    wrapper.update();
       expect(wrapped.find("textarea").prop("value").length).toEqual(0);

  });
});
```

Comment: No worries,Thats the part of development